# Error /bin/sh: ./pipeline.sh: not found powershell v.7

Tags: bash, docker, powershell, dockerfile

I am attempting run a docker image using Powershell v.7. Both files exist in the same folder but I receive the following message:

```
docker container run --rm --name builder -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /c/users/tab45/fod/ch08/sample-app:/usr/src/app -e HUB_USER=<> -e HUB_PWD=<>@j -e repository=ch08-sample-app -e TAG=1.0 builder

**/bin/sh: ./pipeline.sh: not found**
```

---

Pipeline .sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash 

#***Sample Script to build, test and push containerized Node.js applications ***

#build docker image

docker image build -t $HUB_USER/$REPOSITORY:$TAG .

#Run all unit tests

docker container Run $HUB_USER/$REPOSITORY:$TAG npm test

#Login to docker Hub

docker Login -u $HUB_USER -p $HUB_PWD

#Push the image to Docker Hub

docker image push $HUB_USER/$REPOSITORY:$TAG
```

---

Docker Image file:

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk update $$ apk add docker

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

CMD ./pipeline.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a volume mapping like `-v /c/users/tab45/fod/ch08/sample-app:/usr/src/app`, you replace any files in the image in `/usr/src/app` with the mapping. That means that your pipeline.sh script is hidden and can't be found.

To solve that, place it outside of that path. Here I've placed it in `/usr/src` which should fix it

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk update $$ apk add docker
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/
CMD /usr/src/pipeline.sh
```

Also, I don't think alpine images have bash installed, so you might have to change `#!/bin/bash` in your script to `#!/bin/sh`.